# Cross-compile Swift code for Raspberry Pi on macOS

Tags: swift, macos, raspberry-pi3, cross-compiling

What is the easiest / best way to use a macOS Xcode setup to build code for a Raspberry Pi (3b+)?

Some of the builds can be pretty heavy, thus building them on the Raspberry would take too long. Thus it would be preferred to build on macOS. How should I go about doing this?

Note: I'm aware that there is quite some information out there.
However, some of it is a few years old, and Swift is changing quickly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer my own question, the current best solution (very recent) is:
https://github.com/CSCIX65G/swift-mac2arm-x-compile-toolchain

That provides the needed toolchains, etc. for building on macOS for the R Pi.
Best instructions for remote debugging (using lldb) can be found here:
https://lldb.llvm.org/use/remote.html

Note that on macOS you need to use the version of lldb provided by the toolchain, e.g.:

```
[path_to_toolchains]/Toolchains/arm64-swift.xctoolchain/usr/bin/lldb -o "platform select remote-linux" -o "platform connect connect://ipaddress:port" -o "file ./remoteProgram"
```

Still looking to connect the lldb debugger to Xcode run on the Mac. If that can be done, the development cycle is complete.

Comment: Any more updates on this maybe? This seems like a head ache 

Comment: To be more clear: does this allow to use Xcode to write my code and build it for running on a Raspberry Pi?

Comment: @MihaiFratu I haven't been working on this for almost a year, so hard to say if this solution is still valid.
Eventually I got to a setup where I could develop in Visual Studio Code (not Xcode) on my mac, build the code there, and auto-send it to the RPi to be run there.

But it was a head ache 